# How to select exact length in regex?

Tags: regex

```
Input: 123456 789101112 123456 1234561
```

I want only select only 15 digits( not in the middle).

123456 789101112 (length 16) then i need to select 123456. Remaining digits also i need select like this logic. (Group Each match).

```
output:
Match1: 123456
Match2: 789101112 
Match3: 123456 1234561 (This is exact 15 digits from the space)
```

Regex : http://rubular.com/r/Zt0ib08Y6F

Comment: Remove the white spaces and then apply the regex. What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but `123456` is not a 15- or 16-digit substring.

Comment: try `\b\d[\d\s]{0,13}\d\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I _think_ the algorithm is greedily take as many numbers as possible in one batch unless adding more would exceed 15 characters.  If you write a regex for this I swear I'll kiss you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Doesn't that mean the groups should be `123456 789101112`, `123456` and `1234561`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, because your proposed first group exceeds 15 characters in total.  `789101112` gets bumped to the next group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

`\b\d[\d\s]{0,13}\d\b`

See example:

https://regex101.com/r/2mKDH8/1

Comment: 123456 123-123-456 this text i need two match one is Match1: 123456, Match2 : 123-123-456...pls help @ikleschenkov

Comment: @user6479492 then you should try this: `\b\d[\d\s-]{0,13}\d(?!-)\b`. See example: https://regex101.com/r/2WwFSz/1

Comment: Thanks @ikleschenkov. How to support all special characters

Comment: 11111 / 11111 not work..pls see the regex https://regex101.com/r/2WwFSz/3

Comment: @user6479492 try this: `\b\d[\d\s-\/]{0,13}\d(?!-)\b` https://regex101.com/r/6Fe0uH/1

Comment: @user6479492 `\b\d[\d\s-\/.]{0,13}\d(?!-)\b`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this with a set that includes white space. Assuming that the match needs to be bookended by whitespace:

```
\s([0-9\s]{15})\s
```